# Array of a struct with constant parametere in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct, constants

I have defined following struct

```
typedef const struct _txmlAttribute
{
 const char * const ns;
} txmlAttribute;
```

and in following function I want to initialize a dynamic array of my struct:

```
int func(txmlAttribute* attrs){
    attrs = (txmlAttribute*) { {"as"}, {"bs"}};
    return 0;
}

int main(){
   txmlAttribute* attrs;
   func(attrs);
   return 0; 
}
```

but I recieve these warnings:

```
main.c: In function ‘func’:
main.c:13:5: warning: braces around scalar initializer [enabled by default]
     attrs = (txmlAttribute*) { {"as"}, {"bs"}};
 ^
main.c:13:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘(anonymous)’) [enabled by default]
main.c:13:5: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
main.c:13:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘(anonymous)’) [enabled by default]
main.c:13:5: warning: braces around scalar initializer [enabled by default]
main.c:13:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘(anonymous)’) [enabled by default]
main.c:13:5: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
main.c:13:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘(anonymous)’) [enabled by default]
main.c:13:5: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
main.c:13:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘(anonymous)’) [enabled by default]
```

so why is it for? and how I can clear it?

Comment: You're not initializing, you're assigning.

Comment: @haccks it's a compound literal :) Edit : scratch that, it _looks_ like a compound literal. But I guess it's a try at array initialization.

Comment: @Quentin; Yes. But how it is compatible to `txmlAttribute` type ?

Comment: @haccks That would be the initializer for an array of 2 `txmlAttribute`s. I guess.

Comment: @Quentin; Right. I did't thought about that :). [MK's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24614078/2455888) seem to be correct here.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that  `{{"as"}, {"bs"}}` is going to be allocated on stack, and will become invalid* after you leave the scope of the function.

I would do it by writing a "constructor" function which takes fields as arguments, allocating (malloc) space needed for the struct, for its members, initializing them and returning pointer to that struct.  Then the code to populate the array would be something like:

```
txmlAttribute attrs[2];
attrs[0] = make_txml_attr("as");
attrs[1] = make_txml_attr("bs");

txmlAttribute * make_txml_attr(const char * val) {
  txmlAttribute * res = malloc(sizeof(txmlAttribute));   
  res->ns = strdup(val);
  return res;
}


void free_txml_attr(const char ** p_attr) {
   free(*p_attr->ns);
   free(*p_attr);
   *p_attr = NULL;
}
```

(I omitted error checking)

--

invalid - as in access to it will be an undefined behavior

Comment: Also it is a syntax error (see BLUEPIXY's post for the right syntax)

Comment: I compiled the code by gcc and it was not compile error. @MattMcNabb

Comment: So what is your suggestion? how I can do it correct? @MK.

Answer (score 1):

change to `attrs = (txmlAttribute[]) { {"as"}, {"bs"}};` is valid.
but `(txmlAttribute[]) { {"as"}, {"bs"}};` is local scope value.
also Original does not change when you change the pointer argument.
My suggestion is as follows.

```
int func(txmlAttribute **attrs){
    static txmlAttribute att[] =  { {"as"}, {"bs"}};

    *attrs = att;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So this 'static' variable will be remain in memory, how I can free this memory after I used it? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: @rezCash life of a static memory area is up to the end of the application.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to do something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
  char* ns;
} txmlAttribute;

int func(txmlAttribute* attrs){
  attrs[0].ns = malloc(3);
  if (attrs[0].ns == NULL)
    return -1;
  strcpy(attrs[0].ns, "as");
  attrs[1].ns = malloc(3);
  if (attrs[1].ns == NULL)
    return -1;
  strcpy(attrs[1].ns, "bs");
  return 0;
}

int main(){
  txmlAttribute attrs[2];
  func(attrs);
  //do something

  free(attrs[0].ns);
  free(attrs[1].ns);
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I think it is not possible to use strcpy, because **ns** has defined _const_